# How to Delete from from folder in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

i have a web app to upload files to one folder. Now I want to delete the file from that folder using a `WCF` service. In `asp.net` we use `string filePath = Server.MapPath(FPath);` but this is not working in `WCF`.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you just need to change it to:

```
string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(FPath)
```

Comment: Thanks -- .. thats working,  missing the small things might create problem in  development...